# Which ways can sound be produced in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm playing a canvas-based game in chrome. There is no mute option and i'm trying to find the audio-source. It's not flash and it's not the audio-tag. What other things can produce sound in chrome and how can I find it?

Comment: Does audio have to be an element in the DOM tree?

Comment: No, it seems to be in the javascript...

Comment: Examples http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Comment: Why wouldn't you just post the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be using the Web Audio API (different than the HTML5 Audio API). Look for something like `new AudioContext()` in the javascript. You can also try searching the javascript for `.destination` as that would be where the audio is actually being hooked up to the AudioContext's destination (i.e. the speakers).

Answer (score 0):

Look for `new Audio()` object declaration in the source code. It's HTML5 audio API.